# How to get IP's of all network devices in Java

Tags: java, networking, connection, ip, server

I'm working on a project, and basically I need this program to find a list of all connected IP addresses to a network, such as going to your network connections in Windows. I've looked all over the internet, and I cant find what I'm looking for and I hope someone can!

This program cannot just crunch numbers (such as pinging all possible IP addresses), it needs to be faster than that. Being able to just connect to the network and obtain a "list" of all IP's that it can see would be perfect. Using the [docs.oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html) webpage did what it was supposed to, but there were too many extra results (including Eth10, etc). Also, the only IP address it listed that wasnt my own didnt match any active computers, so I dont know what was up with that... (192.168.0.9 was listed, the only other active connection was at 192.168.0.10, maybe I'm missing something?).

What is a way to do this? Sorry if I'm unclear, I'm able to be clearer if there's something specific, hope this helps!

Thanks!

EDIT: I hope this helps; I want to do this in java, because for my designed program to work it needs a list of active IP addresses connectable to the active machine. Meaning that if I run it on a laptop at a school, I need all the IP addresses that I could connect to on the network. It is a network thing, but it does need to be done in java. The purpose is for a file manager, otherwise its pretty tough to explain. Does that help?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  This isn't a programming issue.. this is a networking issue.  Do you mean all the connections to a specific machine?  Do you mean all the internally connected devices with an issued IP on the LAN?  Do you mean all open connections between your internal network and the internet?

Comment: I think you can do it in cmd why do you need to do it in Java?

Comment: If u want to know how to do it in cmd , i can help :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you are asking is via brute force.  It can be done somewhat quickly by creating multiple threads that fire off TCP SYN requests to random IPs on the network (this is what NMap does).  If you had access to the DHCP server then you could likely get a list from that point.  I would warn you to tread very lightly.  Running NMAP or doing port scans on a network is considered an attack by many network admins... you could get yourself in to trouble (they WILL notice).

Comment: So, i can see what you're saying about that being noticed. basically, its something like how in Iron man, he's able to transfer files instantly to different interfaces. That's what I'm trying to do, with the most bare bones required. I am accounting for system security and all that good stuff. Is there a way to get this list, relatively quickly, every 30 seconds or so, without being "flagged" by the admin?

Comment: These kind of activities just inherently fit the profile of a hacking/virus attack.  Most corporate networks/school networks/ etc are going to utilize intrusion detection devices.